# optparse-applicative: Require at least one argument

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments

I'm using the [optparse-applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.4.1) library in an application that takes multiple strings on the command line and performs an action on each one. My first try was this:

```
arguments Just
    ( metavar "EXPR"
    & help "Expressions to render, in zero-based De Bruijn index notation" )
```

Unfortunately, this allows running the program with *no* arguments, even though it doesn't make much sense.

My second attempt involved parsing the first argument separately, then consing it to the remainder of the list:

```
(:) <$> argument Just ( metavar "EXPR" )
    <*> arguments Just ( metavar "EXPR" )
```

This should have worked, but it didn't: when called with `--help`, the parser gobbles it up and processes it instead of displaying the help text.

So my question is: how do I configure optparse to require at least one argument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay – I've [reported this issue](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative/issues/20) to the author of the library (Paolo Capriotti). He replied:

> The problem here is that `arguments` has some special logic to:
>
> - initially ignore arguments starting with '-'
> - accept '--'
> - accept arguments starting with '-' after '--' is encountered
>
> Given this desired behavior, `arguments` cannot simply be implemented as `many argument`.
>
> What we can do to make common use cases like the one in this Issue easier to deal with, is to add a bunch of convenience builders, like:
>
> - `arguments1`, non-empty argument list, with the same behavior as arguments
> - `argument'`, parse 1 argument, ignoring things starting with '-'
>
> This way, many argument' would be similar to arguments (without the special handling of --), and some argument' to arguments1.
>
> Suggestions for better names are welcome. :)

In other words, he added a new function [`arguments1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/optparse-applicative/0.5.0/doc/html/Options-Applicative-Builder.html#v%3aarguments1) to do what I described. That function has been available since version 0.5.

So now my code looks like this:

```
arguments1 Just
    ( metavar "EXPR"
   <> help "Expressions to render, in zero-based De Bruijn index notation" )
```

Thanks, Paolo!

Comment: fyi... as of version 0.9.0 `arguments` and `arguments1` are deprecated in favor of using the `many` and `some` combinators with `argument`.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment.

Comment: @ErikR But `some` with argument does not print useful help messages by default (i.e. no `...` at the end) :-(